# PHP If statement not redirecting on blank string

Tags: php

I have some code that is entering values into a database. I have an IF statement at the start to check if the string `$jobno` is empty and if it is, it redirects back to the form. But its not redirecting just runs the code successfully.

```
if ($jobno=='') {
        header( 'Location: add_job.php?error=1');
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?!

```
 <?php
$status=$_POST["status"];
$jobno=$_POST["jobno"];
$number=$_POST["number"];
$street=$_POST["street"];
$suburb=$_POST["suburb"];
$city=$_POST["city"];
$first_name=$_POST["first_name"];
$first_name = ucfirst($first_name);
$last_name=$_POST["last_name"];
$last_name = ucfirst($last_name);
$landline=$_POST["landline"];
$mobile=$_POST["mobile"];
$fax=$_POST["fax"];
$email=$_POST["email"];

if ($jobno=='') {
    header( 'Location: add_job.php?error=1');
}

$con=mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO jobs (status, jobno, number, street, suburb, city, first_name, last_name, landline, mobile, fax, email)
VALUES ('$status', '$jobno', '$number', '$street', '$suburb', '$city', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$landline', '$mobile', '$fax', '$email')");

mysqli_close($con);

header( 'Location: photo_upload.php?new_job_success=y&jobno=' . $jobno ) ;

?>
```

Comment: if you do `var_dump($jobno);` what does it say?

Comment: Then It should be other than empty string `''`. Instead do strict type comparison `===`

Comment: I hope this isn't your production script!! as the severe lack of sanitisation is terrifying.

Comment: You could also check for if(empty($jobno))

Comment: What do you mean by var_dump($jobno);  DoXicK. Sorry bit of a newbie

Comment: Try if (empty($jobno)) {header ('Location: add_job.php?error=1')}

Comment: Its not the finished script RaggaMuffin-420 but what do you mean by sanitisation? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First of all, go read up on SQL Injection.

Comment: @georgewoofbates please tell me your not developing this for consumer use, and its just a school project or something!  please google `data sanitisation php` or something.

Comment: Will do cbroe. That didn't work allisonc :(

Comment: Use [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and I'm next to convinced that you'll get an error "headers already sent...." - Error reporting meaning, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` placed right after your opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Please choose an answer to close this thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be 2 things

- $jobno is not ''
- since you aren't returning after your redirect, and you are doing a second redirect a bit later, your header would look like:

  - Location: add_job.php?error=1
  - Location: photo_upload.php?new_job_success=y&jobno=

put an `else` clause in your code:

```
<?php
...
if ($jobno=='') {
    header( 'Location: add_job.php?error=1');
}
else {
  $con=mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","database");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else
  {
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO jobs (status, jobno, number, street, suburb, city,first_name, last_name, landline, mobile, fax, email) VALUES ('$status', '$jobno', '$number', '$street', '$suburb', '$city', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$landline', '$mobile', '$fax', '$email')");

    mysqli_close($con);

    header( 'Location: photo_upload.php?new_job_success=y&jobno=' . $jobno ) ;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: definitely advise the `if...else...` as i'm pretty sure the script will run even if you define the header, as the `header` doesn't kill the script.  +1

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 i know that is the problem indeed :-) but it never helps to put them in the right direction to let them properly check a value first. Debugging is such helpful skill!

Comment: did you change your script? as I'd use an else on the `if($jobno=='') { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: Oh right that's a good point using the else. Thanks I'll try that!

Comment: Is there any other way I can redirect without having to use the headers if this is going to be an ongoing problem?

Comment: you could go for a meta-redirect in the header and for a javavascript redirect (location.href = blabla)...

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?php
^---this space
```

is OUTSIDE of your code, so it's output, which makes

```
header( 'Location: add_job.php?error=1');
```

cause a "headers already sent" error.

You are also wide open and begging for an [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by this space is outside of your code? I'm confused

Comment: Basic PHP: Anything not within `<?php ...?>` code blocks is simply output. **ANY** output triggers automatic sending of the response headers to the client. Your `Location:` is such a header, and can't be sent after output has started, because it'd simply become part of the response BODY.

Comment: So I need to put the Header: Location into the <head> tag?

Comment: No. php header() calls having **NOTHING** to do with `<head>` blocks. header() sends an HTTP header. You should go read about the HTTP protocol's request/response formats.

Answer (score 0):

There is an space in the starting which is causing this error. You can't echo any output before sending the headers not even a single space. This small space is causing the header already sent error.You should remove the space on the starting of the php file. Your code should look like this

```
<?php
$status=$_POST["status"];
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score -1):

I think you must to use **isset** function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score -1):

try using this code:

```
if (!isset($_POST["jobno"])) {
    header( 'Location: add_job.php?error=1');
}
```

Comment: makes no difference, if its not set, then PHP will throw a warning and set the variable to `null` and `'' == null` is true.

Comment: it still just goes through fine!